# goMap Clean and Reset

Tags: jquery, google-maps, reset

Can I clean and/or completely reset goMap? I want to remove the points created with `$.goMap.createMarker` and `$.goMap.createPolyline`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution is:

**Remove the DIV data**

```
$("#Map_Temp").removeData();
```

**and create the map again ...**

```
$("#Map_Temp").goMap({
    latitude: XOXOXOX,
    longitude: XOXOXOX,
    zoom: 16,
    maptype: 'ROADMAP'
});
```